# Effect size for contrasts in mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, effect-size, contrasts

I was wondering on how to compute effect sizes for planned contrasts in (generalized) linear mixed effects models.

First, I set up multiple models with main effects and interactions and compared them in an LRT-Test with `anova()`
Reading the paper of [Nakagawa and Schielzeth](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x%4010.1111/%28ISSN%292041-210X.STATSTOO)) I figured how to calculate effect sizes of each model.

Afterwards I calculated contrasts with `summary` using the package `lmertest()` to obtain p values. Now, I would also like to calculate effect sizes for singular contrasts. I read Andy Fields book "discovering statistics using R" where he suggests to use *r*  $r= sqrt(t^2 / (t^2 + df)) $ by Rosenthal (1991).

However, I was wondering because my contrasts are non orthogonal if this is the right approach? Are there any differences for `glmer` and `lmer`?
Any ideas on that?

Btw, I used the `lme4` package.